# Sequence Generator not working on Oracle 18c

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, oracle18c

I have a table with columns id and name which I am creating using this class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xyz")
public class XYZ implements Serializable{
   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "some_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "some_gen", sequenceName = "some_seq", allocationSize = 2)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    //Getter Setter NoArgConstructor AllArgsConstructor


}
```

Now when I run this, table as well as sequence is created. Verified it from SQL Developer. But when I run the following statement I am getting following error.

```
INSERT INTO xyz (name) VALUES ('John');
```

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SOME_USER"."XYZ"."ID")

I am using JPA and Spring Boot.

```
//This is MyBatis. It will be triggered by REST API
@Mapper
public interface XYZMapper {

    @Insert("INSERT INTO xyz (name) VALUES (#{name})")
    public void addNewName(XYZ xyz);
}
```

Comment: Are you running this statement as a Native Query or that was the SQL statement generated by JPA?

Comment: @RobsonFrança This is Native Query. When JPA is generating SQL query then it is sending id as null and again we get the same error ORA-01400

Comment: That's odd. Are you using Hibernate? Can you provide the persistence.xml as well as a code sample?

Comment: @RobsonFrança Updated. I am not using Hibernate hence no persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java.

But, from Oracle's point of view, the fact that you generated the sequence doesn't mean that Oracle will automagically use it. You have to either use it directly, such as

```
insert into xyz (id, name) values (some_seq.nextval, 'John');
```

or create a database trigger which will do it for you:

```
create or replace trigger trg_bi_xyz
  before insert on xyz
  for each row
begin
  :new.id := some_seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

and now you can use `insert` you previously posted:

```
INSERT INTO xyz (name) VALUES ('John');
```

Comment: I agree that this solution will work. Thanks for sharing but I am thinking that can this be done automatically because when I am using ID strategy as IDENTITY then everything works fine, but with Sequence its not working.

Comment: Identity column is something different; a table is created with such a syntax (if your Oracle database version supports it (your does)). In the background, it still uses the sequence, though.